# Grab data from a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array that looks something like this:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Awesomedude123
        [1] => 399,408
        [2] => September 16, 2012
    )

    [2] => Array
    (
        [0] => Username11
        [1] => 1,914,144
        [2] => September 16, 2012
    )

    [3] => Array
    (
        [0] => EpicSurfer
        [1] => 1,031,427
        [2] => September 16, 2012
    )
)
```

What I want to do is grab data from inside it. I want to grab this data from each array:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Awesomedude123
        [1] => 399,408  <----
        [2] => September 16, 2012
    )

    [2] => Array
    (
        [0] => Username11
        [1] => 1,914,144 <----
        [2] => September 16, 2012
    )

    [3] => Array
    (
        [0] => EpicSurfer
        [1] => 1,031,427 <----
        [2] => September 16, 2012
    )
)
```

How can I accomplish this? My actual file is actually much bigger and I want to grab this data from each array. Any help would be highly appreciated! Sorry if my question sounds confusing, I really have no other way to explain it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if you planned to loop through your array but here is an overly easy way:

```
foreach ($array as $index => $data) {
    echo $data[1];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here, assuming `$array` is your main array:

```
foreach ($array as $element) {
    echo $element[1] . '<br />';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
foreach ($x as $k => $v) {
    echo $v[1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$b = array_map(function($item) { return $item[1]; }, $your_array);
```

Check the array_map function on http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need a recusive function like this:

```
function extend( $arr, $myArr=array() ) {
    foreach( $arr as $key => $value ) {
        if( is_array( $key ) ) {
            extend( $arr[ $key ] );
        } else {
            $myArr[ $key ] = $arr[ $key ];
        }
    }
    return $myArr;
}
```

But if you only need access for a single element you need to do is get te specific element with the array keys, like this:

```
$value = $myArray['subArray']['element'];
```